# Object replaced existing object in array instead of being added

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Here's my code:

```
NSMutableArray *ratings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *eachRating = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (UIView *subview in self.rateServiceView.subviews) {

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[RSTapRateView class]]) {

            RSTapRateView *rs = (RSTapRateView *)subview;
            [eachRating setObject:rs.rateId forKey:@"iRatingId"];
            [eachRating setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rs.rating] forKey:@"iRate"];

            [ratings addObject:eachRating];

        }

    }
```

Instead of getting these values:

```
{
        iRate = 1;
        iRatingId = 1;
    },
        {
        iRate = 5;
        iRatingId = 2;
    },
        {
        iRate = 2;
        iRatingId = 3;
    }
```

I'm getting these values:

```
{
        iRate = 2;
        iRatingId = 3;
    },
        {
        iRate = 2;
        iRatingId = 3;
    },
        {
        iRate = 2;
        iRatingId = 3;
    }
```

When I logged the result for each iteration, the last object replaces all the existing objects and add a new object for itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move this line:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *eachRating = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

down to ***below*** this line:

```
    for (UIView *subview in self.rateServiceView.subviews) {
```

That way, you'll create a new "`eachRating`" dictionary which you'll add to your "`ratings`" array.

Comment: great! it works fine now. Thank you so much! I'll keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is because you are assigning different values to same key so new value replaces oldvalue for that key.

So change your code as :

```
  NSMutableArray *ratings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UIView *subview in self.rateServiceView.subviews){

        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[RSTapRateView class]]) {

            NSMutableDictionary *eachRating = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


            RSTapRateView *rs = (RSTapRateView *)subview;
            [eachRating setObject:rs.rateId forKey:@"iRatingId"];
            [eachRating setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rs.rating] forKey:@"iRate"];

            [ratings addObject:eachRating];

        }

    }
```

Comment: +1 to you Nishant, since you're really trying hard to earn that check mark.  :-)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann initially I told the reason for the problem but then I thought to provide him the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require further mutability of the individual dictionaries after this loop you can get a bit more modern and compact by writing it like this:

```
NSMutableArray *ratings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (UIView *subview in self.rateServiceView.subviews) {

    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[RSTapRateView class]]) {

        RSTapRateView *rs = (RSTapRateView *)subview;
        [ratings addObject:@{@"iRatingId":rs.rateId, @"iRate":@(rs.rating)}];

    }

}
```